# Управление ScrollBarом в QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

У меня есть QGraphicsSene с её скроллбарами и есть сигнал/слот(valueChanged/кастомный слот). Когда тригериться скролбар вызывается этот слот но вместе с тем вызывается что ещё внутренне, поскольку результатом есть то что смещение видимой части сцены происходит раньше чем выпонится кастомный слот(который рисует что то на сцене). Это приводит к тому что при движении скролбара картинка на сцене дёргается. Вопрос - как заблокировать эту внутреннюю часть скролбара до того как выполниться кастомный слот?

Comment: Сигналы подключенные к слоту выполняются в произвольном порядке. Заблокировать выполнение "чужих" слотов подключенных к сигналу - нельзя. (Можно только отключить coonection, или заблокировать сигнал для всех.) Попробуйте сформулировать задачу более высокого уровня. Возможно есть решение, не требующие подключения к скроллбару.

Comment: Спасибо, буду искать другое решение